# Excel VBA: Dynamically change cell value in sheet whose name is referenced in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

When a value in a named range ("E10:E23") in the active sheet ("sheet1") is changed, I need VBA to change a given cell ("C7") in another sheet whose name is 2 columns to the left of the cell just changed, to the value of the changed cell in ("sheet1").
Ex:
If ("Sheet1").Range("E15") is changed, Then ("C7") in sheet whose name is in ("sheet1").Range("C15") should be changed to the value in ("sheet1").Range("E15").
If ("Sheet1").Range("E8") is changed, Then ("C7") in sheet whose name is in ("sheet1").Range("C8") should be changed to the value in ("sheet1").Range("E8").
And so on.
What would be the code for that?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Please edit your question to include some screenshots of your data and preferred outcome. Please also include anything you've tried so far. Generally you will get a more positive response that way.

Comment: It's also generally advisable to [edit] your question to include a question

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks demonstration of effort to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code goes in the sheet code for the sheet you have described as "sheet1", not in a module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error GoTo MyExit
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E10:E23")) Is Nothing Then
        Set ws = Sheets(Target.Offset(0, -2).Value)
    ws.Range("C7").Value = Target.Value
    End If
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
MyExit:
    msgbox "Sheetname not found"
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I think it is what you are after.

Justin

Comment: Thank you Justin, Works fine now

Comment: Hi Jay, if the code is what you are after please tick the question off as answered and upvote the response.

Comment: Hi Justin, I'm new to this site and i don't see how i can mark my question as answered. I also tied upvoting your answer but the system wouldn't recognize it because i dont have 15 reputations...

Comment: No problem Jay, there should be a big tick below the upvote buttons but if it is not there all good.